# dplyr::select based on information stored in attributes()

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's create a tibble, add an attribute containing which variables to select later on

```
mytib<-tibble(aa=1:10,bb=21:30,cc=letters[1:10],dd=letters[11:20])
attributes(mytib)$select_me <- c('bb','cc')
```

I thought `select_if` might be able to do it, something like

```
mytib %>% select_if(~(function(x)names(x)%in%attributes(x)$select_me))
```

Well, that doesn't work, but you get the idea.

It's easy to write a function that returns a logical vector based on the attribute information, but how to put it into select, ideally FP style.

```
myfun=function(x)names(x) %in% attributes(x)$select_me
myfun(mytib)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
mytib %>% 
  select(
    one_of(attributes(mytib)$select_me)
  )
```

Comment: That works but requires an explicit mention of `mytib` inside `select`/one_of. Any way to use an anonymous function here?

Comment: Maybe this is closer to what you want? Just write your own function that does it: 
`my_select = function(df){
  df[,attributes(df)[['select_me']]]
};
mytib %>% 
  my_select
`

Comment: It gets the job done. I am still curious to learn if there is something that can be done within `select_x`. The problem with that is this: 
`myf=function(x){
  test<<-(x)
  is.integer(x)
}
mytib %>% select_if(myf)
test # is NULL
`
`select_if` simplifies each column of the tibble to a vector, shedding attributes.